# How to use a file from a client in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, client

I know the server cant access the hard drive or directories of a client, but why when I Hardcode the directory into my application can I access the file and upload it to a SQL database?

Just a plain button

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnImportData" runat="server" OnClick="btnImportData_Click">Import Spreadsheet</asp:LinkButton>
```

then the Code behind

```
  protected void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dbConn.uploadToExcel(@"C:\Users\spadmin\Desktop\ABI Employee List.xlsx");
        }
```

Then I can use that file to update my database and it works.

Why do they then say I cant use directories from the client?

UPDATE

[Link on how to upload to server using Server.Mappath](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/controls/article.php/c19629/File-Uploading-in-ASPNET-20.htm)

Comment: You can't access Server Directories from client system, that is how the SERVER-CLIENT architecture works.
Just think if you get an access of a server what all wonders you can do.
I just can't imagine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code accesses the file on the server.  Regardless of which PC you use to access the web server it is always looking on the server's C drive.

Comment: So when I debug my application, It sees my local C as the server's C drive? Is That why it looks like its working?

Comment: Yeah, when you debug the client pc and the server pc are the same machine.  It won't work if someone else connects to the site though.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode links like that. Allow the user to pick up the file for uploading using [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control.

The path you gave points to your local account's desktop only (Your local server). Actually it is not uploading the file from client's machine.

When you save files to server, use [`Server.MapPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes I know I shouldn't hardcode it, I Just wanted to know Why I can't use a browser to get the Location of a file, but I can hardcode it like that

Comment: See what you meant by using Server.MapPath(). Added a link to my question to help with that. Thank you