# How to Upload file from Client to Sever Without access to Client Directories? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, client

Every where I read of being able to "Upload files from the client PC to the Server" but HOW will you do this if you don't have access to the clients directories?

How will the client select what files to upload if the server does not have access to them?

Links on How to do this.

[C#, Asp.net Uploading files to file server…?](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100315003227AA5URUX)

[Uploading files to a web server with ASP.Net](http://delphi.about.com/od/aspnet/l/aa070604a.htm)

[Uploading In ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140211/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/091201-1.shtml)

[My Previous question telling me that the server does not have access to the client pc/directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355855/how-to-use-a-file-from-a-client-in-asp-net)

--UPDATE--
So thanks to the comments and answers I Understand now.

- The server CANNOT access directories and files on the client. BUT
- The client can push through files to the client that can then use the
  files.

Comment: with an input of type "file" HTML control, and the appropriate .NET code... You already seem to have quite some links so what ? The client will push the info, it's not the server pulling it...

Comment: Ohhh,, So the client "Gives access"(in a way) to those directories then. I thought they don't have access at ALL

Comment: The client doesn't give access... It pushes the a copy of the file up, sending a binary stream to the server. The server never gets to know what folder the original file was in, who was its owner etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [upload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx), so that the user can upload files manually. If you want to pull files from the user's PC without interaction with the user, then ASP.net won't do that for you. You should look into WCF or other frameworks.